# svn: E000104: Error running context: Connection reset by peer

Tags: svn

While `svn update` works perfectly, `svn commit` fails within few seconds with the following error:

```
$ svn commit -m ""
svn: E000104: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: E000104: Error running context: Connection reset by peer
```

My client svn is **1.8.8** while the server uses **1.8.10**. I also managed to commit from the server using the same credentials as my client machine, without any trouble at all.

Comment: Same error but in my context was a firewall problem.

Answer (score 0):

I faced with same problem. I removed half of differences (there was mostly whitespace handling) and only then commit succeeded.
Probably, problem in big diff data. We are using usvn.